# How to run Vim shortcuts without exiting insert mode

Tags: vim

**For instance**, I'd like to use <kbd>$</kbd> to move to the end of the line, without going through <kbd>Esc</kbd> for it.

Just <kbd>$</kbd>, and not <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>$</kbd>.

Is there a way?

*One solution could be*: press another key(/combo), say, Ctrl+Shift, do what I want in "temporary normal mode", then when I release those keys I'm back in insert mode... if that's possible.

Comment: Why not `<End>`? Or Cmd+Right on Mac OS X?

Comment: @romainl maybe `<END>` is not easy to type, like my keyboard: `Fn+,`

Comment: It was only an example @romainl, I want to be able to do more. Please see my comments on Kent's answer.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect your real goal.

Comment: You're right, "for instance" is easy to miss. Now it is edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna perform one normal mode command in insert mode you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then normal mode command. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> will move you to the end of line in insert mode (like <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: In order to physically achieve that, I'm hitting: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`o`, then still holding `Ctrl`+`Shift` I'm hitting `4` on my keyboard. But I'm seeing an error about "marker invalid" at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it: `Ctrl`+`o`, then `Shift`+`4`: TADA, I'm at end of line and back in `Insert mode` :3

Comment: FWIW, this is 1 keystroke more than `ESC` `Shift + a`

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason why you want to go to the end of the line? Vi is built to mainly be operated in normal mode, not insert mode (especially when it comes to movement).

For example, if you wanted to go to the end of the line and start adding text, you would type <kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> if you were in insert mode at the time).

If you wanted to go to the end of the line so you could add a newline, you could type <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to start a new line and place you in insert mode.

If you gave us more context as to what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, we may be able to come up with a more efficient workflow.

Comment: Balthamos, exactly, as you see I have to press `Esc`, do what I want, then I press `i` again. Instead, I want to press another key(/combo), say, `Ctrl`+`Shift`, do what I want in "temporary normal mode", then when I release those keys I'm back in insert mode.

Comment: Vi may not be the editor for you then. Emacs operates on this "always in insert mode" mentality. For example `Ctrl + e` takes you to the end of the line, `Ctrl + a` takes you to the beginning of the line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
inoremap $ <ESC>A
```

give this a try. It may do what you want, but make inserting `$`  harder.

Comment: Thanks. But `$` was just an example, I want to be able to use any Normal mode command I want with perhaps a modifier key pressed, without having to get out of Insert mode first.

Comment: all **normal mode** commands? then go to **normal mode** first, you can create all `imap` mappings, but how can you insert text? it seems that almost all letters `a-z`  are normal mode commands. @adityamenon

Comment: They are. Thus, I want to be able to press another key as a "temporary shortcut" to move to *normal mode*. Then when I release that key, I'm back in insert mode.

Comment: @adityamenon, you can use `<C-o>` to leave insert mode temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Right

```
map! <C-Right> <Esc>A
```